# Need help using Lookup in Google Sheets with conditional statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to lookup dates in a spreadsheet and return them to another spreadsheet depending on whether or not the first and last names match.

In one tab I have a column of first names, another column of last names and another column of dates.

In another tab I have the same columns of first and last names(plus some) but need to fill in the dates and if no date exists leave it blank.

Can provide an example if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula may work as you want

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&LEFT(B2:B,SEARCH(" ",B2:B&" ")-1),{Sheet1!A:A&Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C:C},2,0)))`

Example sheet is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZnjnL6DzXCsgOQgnOrVoiq4l3fX6Qh09zsz89XmK54/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much! Elegant and simple solution!